# Slient crash when calls to ffmpeg's libav exist

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, mingw-w64, libav, libavformat

I have a fairly simple example.

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main(int, char **)
{
  AVFormatContext *format = 0; // avformat_alloc_context();

  // avformat_open_input(&format, "http://s5radio.ponyvillelive.com:8026/stream.mp3", NULL, NULL);
  // avformat_find_stream_info(format, NULL);

  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I this outputs "Hello, world!" and I can set break points but the moment I uncomment anything calling  avformat code the program silently closes with no error and no break points are hit making it impossible to debug.

An example would be changing `AVFormatContext *format = 0;` to `AVFormatContext *format = avformat_alloc_context();` or uncommenting `avformat_open_input(&format, "http://s5radio.ponyvillelive.com:8026/stream.mp3", NULL, NULL);`. Without breakpoints or errors how do I solve?

Update:
This is what I get from the debugger:

> ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
> The program 'path\to\my\project\LibavPlayground.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).

Update2:

this is my cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(LibavPlayground VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX C)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED) 
pkg_check_modules(LIBAV REQUIRED libavutil libavcodec libavformat)
include_directories(${LIBAV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -Wno-deprecated-declarations")

include_directories(include PUBLIC)
include_directories(src PRIVATE)

file(GLOB SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

add_executable(LibavPlayground ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(LibavPlayground ${LIBAV_LIBRARIES})
```

and all the libav* libraries were installed with a single `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg` command

Comment: Call `av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();` before any calls to ffmpeg functions.

Comment: @S.M. those methods are deprecated.

Comment: Also if I use -Wno-deprecated-declarations and call `av_register_all(); avcodec_register_all();` anyway they cause the same behavior.

Comment: The code shown (with the `avformat_*` calls uncommented) behaves as expected for me.  Can you clarify what you mean by `"...the program silently closes"`?  If you run it under a debugger does it never reach the `std::cout << ...` statement?

Comment: @G.M. yes it never reaches the `std::cout` `main` is never called.

Comment: Have all the libraries and the application been home-built with the same toolset? This looks like a build error or incompatible library versions. Stuff like that tends to happen for mixed cygwin/MingW builds, for example.

Comment: @tofro all the libraries are part of ffmpeg so I got them with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-ffmpeg` and Im using cmake and gcc from the same mingw-w64 toolset

Comment: @G.M. meaning it exits with code 0 immediately.

Comment: I see an error c0000139 (Entry point not found). This hints to a problem with your installed shared libs.

Comment: @tofro I reinstalled everything and now I'm getting c0000135. where do you fins what those codes mean?

Comment: Trying to clone ffmpeg source and linking the source give me the same results

Comment: C0000135 is "DLL not found". You can look up the Windows error codes on MS site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/1bc92ddf-b79e-413c-bbaa-99a5281a6c90

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233538/discussion-between-william-lohan-and-tofro).

Comment: You can use https://www.dependencywalker.com/ to check which DLLs are used/missing

Comment: @Brecht Sanders thank you I did that and it can't find dozens of API-MS-WIN-CORE-*.DLL files

Comment: @WilliamLohan Those are in yellow and you can ignore them. Check or errors marked in red.

Comment: @Brecht Sanders I'm now using https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies  and the ones in red are api-ms-win-core-comm-l1-1-0.dll api-ms-win-core-xstate-l2-1-1.dll and ext-ms-win-oobe-query-l1-1-0.dll

Answer (score 0):

The current solution is to use WSL instead of MinGw as I don't duplicate the issue in WSL. Although I really hope someone out there has a real solution.